# RVM is not working over SSH

Tags: ruby, ssh, rvm

RVM is not working over SSH.

At the command-line:

```
leifg@host:~$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
```

Connected over SSH:

```
local:~$ ssh leifg@server 'which ruby'
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

How do I get SSH to use the same Ruby as it is on the system?

I already verified some prequisites:

- Ruby was already installed using `apt-get install ruby`. Does that make any difference?
- `sshd_config` has the option "PermitUserEnvironment yes", and I restarted the daemon.

The .bashrc on the server contains these lines, but I see the same behavior when I remove them:

```
if [ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then
  . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
elif [ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ] ; then
  . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
fi
```

Comment: what do you mean `over ssh`? over ssh to your same system?

Comment: i want to execute ruby on another system using the ssh user@host 'command' syntax like explained in the 2 code snippets. in this case these are 2 separate machines.

Comment: wow. so you should install rvm on your remote system first

Comment: @Michael-kohl said, your commands won't be executed at shell, but @leifg what happens if you run this? `local:~$ ssh leifg@server 'source ~/.bashrc && which ruby'`

Comment: tried several tricks: ssh user@server 'source ~/.bashrc && which ruby', ssh user@server 'bash -c 'which ruby'" but that didn't help. I don't want to add the specific path to /etc/environment as this would overwrite it for all user (I only want to have it for a specific user). Is there NO way to execute whatever rvm is executing on ssh login?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the `ssh` man page:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.

This should mean that your `.bashrc` won't get sourced, so RVM doesn't get set up.

**Solution**

This did the trick in the end:

```
ssh <host> bash --login -c <command>
```

Start bash as a login shell through SSH and then start the RVM installed Ruby via SSH's `-c` option.

Comment: so in other words: there is no solution?

Comment: Have you tried manually sourcing before executing your command? Or setting the appropriate env variables manually?

Comment: see comment on my question, didn't help

Comment: Last idea: `ssh <host> bash --login -c <command>`. Run bash as a login shell through SSH and then run your Ruby script via the `-c` option.

Comment: @MichaelKohl, oh, don't work for me, please, could you see my question? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727016/how-to-change-rvm-gemset-over-ssh-on-os-x-server)

Answer (score 52):

Actually, your ~/.bashrc will be executed. The problem is usually that one adds the

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

... snippet at the bottom of the file. However, the default .bashrc on ubuntu systems includes the following near the top

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

That call will stop executing the rest of the script and will therefore not set the proper paths. So you can either put the rvm call at the top of the file or remove the return call.

Comment: This is the right solution! Copy the snippet from above and append "rvm --default 1.9.2" at the top of your .bashrc and you are golden.

Comment: Well actually `~/.bashrc` is not always executed.

Comment: Finally this solved it. Thx a lot. Goddamn this was difficult to find.

Comment: This solved it for me on Ubuntu. It might be helpful to know that in my case, the default .bashrc code for "If not running interactively, don't do anything" was slightly different: `case $- in *i*) ;; *) return;; esac`.

Comment: You may want to make sure the path above is correct on your machine. Mine was in a different place. I used this search function ```find / -type f -name "rvm"``` to find out that my RVM was elsewhere and used this command successfully ```[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*```. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Actually there's totally another, more safe and lightweight option.

You add "**PermitUserEnvironment yes**" somewhere to your **sshd_config** in /etc/(open)ssh

Now you are allowed to specify user environment in /home/user/.ssh/environment. So what do you put there ?

Just something like :

```
user# env | grep rvm > ~/.ssh/environment
```

so it looks like below :

```
user@app3:~$ cat ~/.ssh/environment 
rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02
IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/.irbrc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm
rvm_prefix=/usr/local
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
rvm_version=1.14.5 (stable)
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global
```

Note: this also works work user-install RVM (not only for the system wide)

Now your are able to use ruby in ssh non interactive sessions :

```
ssh user@app3 'ruby --version'
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
```

Voila!

Comment: I like this one best, it definitely seems the most clean.  It worked great for me.  Thank you! (oh and I'm using CentOS with VirtualMin)

Comment: I don't like that this uses the exact version numbers. Why not leave that to rvm?

Comment: @wojciechz Referring to my previous comment, I can see that the rubies paths could be changed to "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/default" but what about the gem paths?

Comment: I'm sure there's a "default" or universal path for gems but why using the "default" path when you want to specify your own custom path? E.g. one user running 3 apps with 3 different ruby versions?

Comment: I think this should be the best answer :)

Answer (score 3):

“rvm” has two invocation bugs: the default installation drops the file `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and believes any bash trick is now globally available. – This assumption is wrong.

Files in `/etc/profile.d/` are “sourced” on login, but maybe not from bash, maybe not even from a shell. So the `cd` hook it installs is not there after the shell which runs these files exits. Actually, because of the buggy way “rvm” installs this hook, it is already gone once you run naked `bash` in a login-shell!

I don’t know if “rvm” supports an explicit invocation for virtual environments, without relying on `cd`ing into some directory (that I consider the second bug).

There is one sane workaround:

Make your shell source `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` from e.g. `~/.bashrc`. `.bashrc` is executed from any non-login bash, and login-bash is usually setup to source `.bashrc` from those login-shell files like `~/.profile`

For your ssh problem: should a proper ssh-shell not be login-shell anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I've just added at the top of ~/.bashrc (for git user) this string:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned solutions work certainly fine, but mine was to run

```
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/<ruby version>@<gemset version>
```

at the start of the remote ssh call. Something like:

```
ssh -l <remote username> <server ip> "source /usr/local/rvm/environments/<ruby version>@<gemset version> ; <rest of the remote script>"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. (if using Capistrano) *Don't* use rvm1/capistrano3 or rvm/capistrano; *don't* set :pty.
2. Change `~/.rvmrc` for the runner user, on the server, to this — note that it has to come *before* the line where it kills itself when not running interactively:

```bash
# get rvm for non-interactive shells (eg capistrano) too
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
export rvm_is_not_a_shell_function=0

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I realized, that I accidentally installed RVM for multiple users, too. After deleting the directory **/usr/local/rvm** and edit **~/.bashrc** like zoonmix suggested, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on the server you have done something like `rvm --default 1.9.2` to set RVM's Ruby to be the default. Otherwise, it will always use the default system Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

zoomix's is the best solution. But when you change with "ruby rvm use system" in terminal or what else you get an error :
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, is not at first place.... To solve that put the snippet just before the return instead of at the top of the .bashrc file (Debian Jessie here)

```
case $- in
*i*) ;;
  *) 
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
  return;; esac
```