# Merge Request not working GitLab

Tags: git, ubuntu, merge, gitlab

I have been trying to merge two branches with `GitLab` But I am keep getting this message. I checked no branch is protected.

**You can accept this request automatically. If you still want to do it manually - click here for instructions**  after this merge request button disables.

Tried **`bundle exec rake gitlab:app:enable_automerge RAILS_ENV=production`**

**Error:**

***could not locate Gemfile***

Being a total noob to GitLab and Ubuntu I am having hard time understanding this.

**githost.log**

```
May 13, 2013 09:59 -> ERROR -> Command failed [1]: /opt/gitorious-2.4.12-1/git/bin/git --git-dir=/opt/gitlab-5.1.0-2/apps/gitlab/gitlab-satellites/testairtdl/.git push origin master

remote: hooks/update:10: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)[K

remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master[K

To /opt/gitlab-5.1.0-2/apps/gitlab/repositories/testairtdl.git

! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to '/opt/gitlab-5.1.0-2/apps/gitlab/repositories/testairtdl.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [gitlab-shell/issues/12](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/12), you must use the wrong ruby version when executing gitlab.

Even if ruby 1.9.3 is installed, the [ruby might not be correct over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918536/rvm-is-not-working-over-ssh).

That same issue page includes:

> `ssh git@blah` will try calling whatever is in `command=` in authenticated_keys without any login/interactive shells, therefore skiping any `.*profile/rc` files and, as a result, not having `rvm` loaded and using system ruby which is 1.8.7.

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158894/6309), make sure to include in your `.bashrc`:

```
# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

***before***

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: I dont have rvm installed. :(

Comment: @AhmedDurrani it doesn't matter, the main point of my answer is: the wrong ruby version must be executed.

Comment: I have removed ruby1.8 and installed ruby1.9.3 still I am getting this error. When I installed GitLab it came with ruby1.8 what should i do?

Comment: @AhmedDurrani read the suggestions of https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/12, checking for instance what `ssh git@yourGitLabServer ruby -v` returns.

Comment: @AhmedDurrani but if you truly did install GitLab with ruby1.8.7, I would rather redo entirely the GitLab installation with the *right* required ruby version (1.9.3), to be on the safe side.

Comment: let me try installing it again.

Comment: installed GitLab again with Ruby 1.9.3 still I am not able to automatically merge code. Please Help! A fresh install what I just did. Gem is also pointing to 1.9.3

Comment: @AhmedDurrani then there must be a wrong ruby left somewhere. As mentioned in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/12: "`require_relative` is a `Kernel` method (must be in `main:Object`) since ruby 1.9.2p180". If you still have the *same* error message, you are still not using the right ruby when used from a client over ssh (even though your installation has been done with the right one (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq#requirements)

Comment: then could you please guide me how should I do that. I am totally new to gitLab as well as Ubuntu. :(

Comment: @AhmedDurrani as mentioned above: `ssh git@yourGitLabServer ruby -v` would be a first test. Also, editing your question detailing the steps you do for getting that error: what do you do from the client in order for the web interface to display that message? Finally, look on your server for any trace of an old ruby.

Comment: I execute this `bundle exec rake gitlab:app:enable_automerge RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: this error appears only when I tries to automerge code in GitLab

Answer (score 1):

If you run the rake command from the GitLab folder, you will not get the could not locate Gemfile