# How to execute `bundle exec command` in guest OS shell from host OS shell with vagrant

Tags: rvm, bundler, vagrant

I got vagrant box. When I log in with `vagrant ssh`, I execute in shell:

```
cd app
bundle exec cucumber
```

and get cucumber tests running.

Now I need to do `bundle exec whatever` from my host OS shell.

I tried:

```
~/vbox > vagrant ssh -c 'cd app; bundle exec cucumber'
https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git (at rails4) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

~/vbox > vagrant ssh -c 'cd app; pwd; ls; bundle list'
/home/vagrant/app
account  bin      certs   config.ru  db        features  Gemfile.lock  log        Rakefile   script       spec  vbox
app      Capfile  config  data       Gemfile   lib       public        README.md  tmp        vendor
Gems included by the bundle:
https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git (at rails4) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

~/vbox > vagrant ssh -c 'ruby -v; rvm list'
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

How can execute a command exactly in the same environment as I do that interactively?

UPDATE:

```
> vagrant ssh -c 'cd app; bundle env'
Bundler 1.6.5
Ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 353) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygems 2.2.2
rvm 1.25.28 (version)
GEM_HOME /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet
GEM_PATH /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)


Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use Oracle adapter for reading from Siebel
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git', branch: 'rails4'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use slim for markup
gem 'slim-rails'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

gem 'quiet_assets'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

group :development do
  gem 'thin'
end

# Use Capistrano for deployment
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

# Use RSpec for testing
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-mocks'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :test do
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec'
end

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Use DS gems
gem 'ds-sns', git: 'git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/ds-sns-gem.git', branch: 'sns2'
gem 'ds-siebel', git: 'git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/ds-siebel-gem.git'
gem 'ds-spark', git: 'git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/DS-Spark-gem.git'

# Helpers
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'letter_opener', group: :development
gem 'keepass-password-generator'

# Localization
gem 'russian'

# Use curb for working with external services
gem 'curb'

# Use workflow as state machine
gem 'workflow'

# Use whenever for cron tasks
gem 'whenever', require: false


Gemfile.lock
GIT
  remote: git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/DS-Spark-gem.git
  revision: 1ec2a4342f23c41c4c67030d3488563a26ea27dc
  specs:
    ds-spark (0.0.1)
      savon (= 2.1.0)

GIT
  remote: git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/ds-siebel-gem.git
  revision: 55b78fd651c972f667c6e019ba5ce9bcf22518ee
  specs:
    ds-siebel (0.0.1)
      savon (= 2.1.0)

GIT
  remote: git@github.com:BusinessEnvironment/ds-sns-gem.git
  revision: 6430105e8efccd30de031017f91935c02bd03853
  branch: sns2
  specs:
    ds-sns (0.0.1)
      andand
      curb
      guid
      memoist
      rails (>= 4.0.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced.git
  revision: f15de843c572f1d73a52907cb47f8a4b884c5ec5
  branch: rails4
  specs:
    activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.3)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.3)
      activemodel (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    acts-as-taggable-on (3.0.1)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    akami (1.2.2)
      gyoku (>= 0.4.0)
      nokogiri
    andand (1.3.3)
    arel (4.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    awesome_print (1.2.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.1.4)
    byebug (2.7.0)
      columnize (~> 0.3)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capistrano (3.1.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-unicorn (0.1.1)
      capistrano (>= 3.1.0)
    capybara (2.3.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    capybara-webkit (1.2.0)
      capybara (>= 2.0.2, < 2.4.0)
      json
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    columnize (0.8.9)
    crack (0.4.2)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    cucumber (1.3.16)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.1)
    cucumber-rails (1.4.1)
      capybara (>= 1.1.2, < 3)
      cucumber (>= 1.3.8, < 2)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rails (>= 3, < 5)
    curb (0.8.5)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    database_cleaner (1.3.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    email_spec (1.6.0)
      launchy (~> 2.1)
      mail (~> 2.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    exception_notification (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.4)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    gherkin (2.12.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
    guid (0.1.1)
    gyoku (1.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httpi (2.0.2)
      rack
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.15.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    keepass-password-generator (0.1.1)
    kgio (2.9.2)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.2.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    memoist (0.10.0)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_magick (3.7.0)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.4)
    multi_test (0.1.1)
    net-scp (1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.8.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    nori (2.0.4)
    pg (0.17.1)
    polyglot (0.3.4)
    pry (0.10.0)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-byebug (1.3.3)
      byebug (~> 2.7)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.1)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7)
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activerecord (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.3)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails-observers (0.1.2)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    railties (4.0.3)
      actionpack (= 4.0.3)
      activesupport (= 4.0.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.13.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (4.1.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    ref (1.0.5)
    rspec-core (2.14.7)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
    rspec-rails (2.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    ruby-oci8 (2.1.7)
    russian (0.6.0)
      i18n (>= 0.5.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.3)
    sass (3.2.14)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    savon (2.1.0)
      akami (~> 1.2.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      gyoku (~> 1.0.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
      nori (~> 2.0.3)
      wasabi (~> 3.0.0)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    simple_form (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0, < 4.1)
    slim (2.0.2)
      temple (~> 0.6.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (2.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      slim (~> 2.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    sprockets (2.10.1)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sshkit (1.3.0)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh
      term-ansicolor
    subexec (0.2.3)
    temple (0.6.7)
    term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
      tins (~> 1.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.1)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.6.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.7.1)
    tins (1.0.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.4.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unicorn (4.8.2)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    vcr (2.9.2)
    wasabi (3.0.0)
      httpi (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.0)
    webmock (1.18.0)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
    whenever (0.9.2)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.4)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    workflow (1.1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter!
  acts-as-taggable-on
  awesome_print
  cancan
  capistrano
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano3-unicorn
  capybara-webkit
  carrierwave
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  cucumber-rails
  curb
  database_cleaner
  ds-siebel!
  ds-sns!
  ds-spark!
  email_spec
  exception_notification
  factory_girl_rails
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-fileupload-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  kaminari
  keepass-password-generator
  letter_opener
  mini_magick
  pg
  pry-byebug
  pry-stack_explorer
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 4.0.3)
  rails-observers
  rspec-mocks
  rspec-rails
  ruby-oci8
  russian
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  simple_form
  slim-rails
  therubyracer
  thin
  timecop
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn
  vcr
  webmock
  whenever
  workflow
```

Comment: Please add the output from `vagrant ssh -c 'cd app; bundle env'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918536/rvm-is-not-working-over-ssh

Comment: @TimMoore, here it is

Answer (score 0):

@TimMoore

Many thanks to Tim! 
Being inspired by your comment I could look at the problem from a different angle. I compared the output of command `vagrant ssh -с cd app; env > 4`, executed from host OS and the output of `env > 3` executed in guest OS shell:

```
> diff 3 4
1c1
< XDG_SESSION_ID=4
---
> XDG_SESSION_ID=52
3c3
< GEM_HOME=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
---
> GEM_HOME=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet
5,6c5
< TERM=screen
< SSH_CLIENT=10.0.2.2 50175 22
---
> TERM=xterm
8c7,8
< OLDPWD=/home/vagrant/app 
---
> SSH_CLIENT=10.0.2.2 65390 22
> OLDPWD=/home/vagrant
10c10
< SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
---
> SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/3
15,39c15
< SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-aFehksOsW6/agent.6453
< TERMCAP=SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\
<       :DO=\E[%dB:LE=\E[%dD:RI=\E[%dC:UP=\E[%dA:bs:bt=\E[Z:\
<       :cd=\E[J:ce=\E[K:cl=\E[H\E[J:cm=\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\E[3g:\
<       :do=^J:nd=\E[C:pt:rc=\E8:rs=\Ec:sc=\E7:st=\EH:up=\EM:\
<       :le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\E[H:nw=\EE:ta=^I:is=\E)0:\
<       :li#31:co#119:am:xn:xv:LP:sr=\EM:al=\E[L:AL=\E[%dL:\
<       :cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:dl=\E[M:DL=\E[%dM:dc=\E[P:DC=\E[%dP:\
<       :im=\E[4h:ei=\E[4l:mi:IC=\E[%d@:ks=\E[?1h\E=:\
<       :ke=\E[?1l\E>:vi=\E[?25l:ve=\E[34h\E[?25h:vs=\E[34l:\
<       :ti=\E[?1049h:te=\E[?1049l:us=\E[4m:ue=\E[24m:so=\E[3m:\
<       :se=\E[23m:mb=\E[5m:md=\E[1m:mr=\E[7m:me=\E[m:ms:\
<       :Co#8:pa#64:AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm:op=\E[39;49m:AX:\
<       :vb=\Eg:G0:as=\E(0:ae=\E(B:\
<       :ac=\140\140aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:\
<       :po=\E[5i:pf=\E[4i:Km=\E[M:k0=\E[10~:k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:\
<       :k3=\EOR:k4=\EOS:k5=\E[15~:k6=\E[17~:k7=\E[18~:\
<       :k8=\E[19~:k9=\E[20~:k;=\E[21~:F1=\E[23~:F2=\E[24~:\
<       :F3=\E[1;2P:F4=\E[1;2Q:F5=\E[1;2R:F6=\E[1;2S:\
<       :F7=\E[15;2~:F8=\E[17;2~:F9=\E[18;2~:FA=\E[19;2~:kb=:\
<       :K2=\EOE:kB=\E[Z:kF=\E[1;2B:kR=\E[1;2A:*4=\E[3;2~:\
<       :*7=\E[1;2F:#2=\E[1;2H:#3=\E[2;2~:#4=\E[1;2D:%c=\E[6;2~:\
<       :%e=\E[5;2~:%i=\E[1;2C:kh=\E[1~:@1=\E[1~:kH=\E[4~:\
<       :@7=\E[4~:kN=\E[6~:kP=\E[5~:kI=\E[2~:kD=\E[3~:ku=\EOA:\
<       :kd=\EOB:kr=\EOC:kl=\EOD:km:
---
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-iMxngt4dR0/agent.29396
42c18
< PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin
:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin
---
> PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/home/
vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/home/vagrant/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:
/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
44,45c20
< STY=6524.pts-0.cabinet
< PWD=/home/vagrant
---
> PWD=/home/vagrant/app
51a27
> rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.0.0-p353
53,55c29,30
< WINDOW=1
< SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.2.2 50175 10.0.2.15 22
< GEM_PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
---
> GEM_PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
> SSH_CONNECTION=10.0.2.2 65390 10.0.2.15 22
56a32
> rvm_delete_flag=0
58d33
< LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
59a35
> LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
```

Then I noticed that the command from the host OS uses a gemset `ds-cabinet`

```
GEM_HOME=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ds-cabinet
```

while the command in the guest OS shell uses a gemset `global`

```
GEM_PATH=/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
```

The gemset `ds-cabinet` was used because there was `app/.ruby-gemset` file which contained `ds-cabinet` string.

When I specified ruby version and gemset explicitely, the command from host OS succeeded.

```
vagrant ssh -c 'cd app; rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@global; xvfb-run bundle exec cucumber'
```

**Conclusion:**

Despite there was `app/.ruby-gemset` pointed to the `ds-cabinet` gemset, actually Bundler, being called locally in guest OS shell, used the `global` gemset, while being called as remote command from host OS, it used the `ds-cabinet` gemset, which eventually was empty.

So, I set `app/.ruby-gemset` to `global`, and the host OS command done well.